# Is there a difference between executing a bash script and doing it manually?

Tags: linux, bash, svn, centos

So, this was happening to me for the last two days. I'm trying to set up a subversion repository with the help of SaltStack and a very simple bash script.

What Salt does for this matter is pretty simple, it just moves `10-subversion.conf` from the master to `/root/` on the minion(slave) and installs neded packages such as `subversion`, `httpd` and `mod_dav_svn`.

After all this happens, the next script runs:

```
#!/bin/bash

mv -f /root/10-subversion.conf /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf
mkdir /var/www/svn
svnadmin create /var/www/svn/repo
chown -R apache.apache /var/www/svn/repo
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svn/repo
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/svn/repo
systemctl restart httpd
mkdir /mnt/logs
touch /mnt/logs/log
svn checkout http://localhost/svn/repo
svn checkout http://localhost/svn/repo /mnt/logs/
```

After that, I get an error with the svn repo not being able to load.

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://localhost/svn/repo'
XML parse error at line 1: no element found (http://localhost/svn/repo)
```

Weird thing here, and that's the reason of the question is that, if I run every command individually (I literally copy&paste from the script to the CLI), works.

So, is it just that subversion is failing randomly or is there an actual difference between executing a script and doing it manually?

**Edit:**

Somehow, I tried to do it again by copy&pasting the commands from the script and it failed. I then realised that, when testing it, I used to modify `10-subversion.conf` manually with an editor but now I was moving it instead, so I recovered the snapshot, did it again editing the file manually and worked. I checked permissions and ownership of the file when moving it and when editing it, both are the same (as follow):

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 120 abr 10 09:18 /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf
```

Comment: How do you run the script ? What is the exect error ?

Comment: The script is run through SaltStack with `cmd.script` and I'm posting the error on the question

Comment: Should be the same. But Exec context can be different. In a cron sometime PATH or HOME is not set. Ptty can modify the behavior too. Is the script running with the same user ?

Comment: The script is run as `root` and it's not the first time I use Salt, there's actually some scripts more being executed and they work nicely

Comment: Is it possible that there is some `alias`/`bash function` in place, which is overriding the commands in this script? You can have functions named `svn`, which can internally call `command svn` with some additional parameters or environment.

Comment: @anishsane nope, it's just that script. In fact, I'm running it individually when executing Salt, in case any of the others may cause conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it, so I'll make this the answer as it's what helped me but, in case someone reaches here, read the other ones as they are pretty usefull.

So, basically, my problem was Selinux. This is the context of the file when moved:

```
ls -lahZ /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf
```

> -rw-r--r--. root root `unconfined_u`:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf

and this is the context of any other file inside `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/`:

```
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 01-cgi.conf
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 10-php.conf
```

So, the problem was having `unconfined_u` instead of `system_u`

Answer (score 3):

The probable explanation is that the webserver has not completed its restart when you attempt to run `svn checkout`.  The `systemctl restart httpd` command is restarting a daemon, and doesn't know when the daemon has finished its initialization, and has started listening for HTTP requests.

Possible solutions:

1. Run `sleep 10` or similar after the restart.
2. Use `curl` or `wget` in a loop to "probe" the daemon, waiting until you get success response from a GET.

Comment: Good answer, tho it's not because of that, I already test it. I edited the post, in case it can bring some light.

Comment: plus1. Alternate to `wget`: `echo -n Waiting for server to start...;until nc localhost 80 </dev/null &>/dev/null; do echo -n . ; sleep 0.1; done`

Comment: But adding sleeps can not hurt and it s safe

Comment: @anishsane - The problem with just using `nc` is that you can't easily detect the case where the daemon is "up" but returning non-success responses.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
#!/bin/bash

mv -f /root/10-subversion.conf /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf
mkdir /var/www/svn
svnadmin create /var/www/svn/repo
chown -R apache.apache /var/www/svn/repo
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svn/repo
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/svn/repo
systemctl stop httpd &&
systemctl start httpd &&
mkdir /mnt/logs
touch /mnt/logs/log
svn checkout http://localhost/svn/repo
svn checkout http://localhost/svn/repo /mnt/logs/
```

Comment: I missunderstood the answer, sorry. Anyways, I know it's not about commands running too fast.

Comment: && doesnt run commands in background, it waits until the last command was excecuted succesful and then starts the next one